# Is there a perceptual DeltaRGB comparison of two colours (i.e., like DeltaE2000)?

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, rgb

Is there a reliable Delta RGB formula or code snippet that does colour Delta of the full RGB tri stim values, like how DeltaE 2000/cmc does Lab/Lch that takes *perceptual* differences into account?

The RGB Colourspace could be any, but if it needed to be a particular one I could keep it sRGB for the calculations. C# is preferred, but I can convert from any language.

I currently have a very basic RGB delta formula, but I would like to implement something that gets a truer sense of perceptual colour difference. Current right now is

```
float delta = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(r1-r2, 2) + Math.Pow(g1-g2, 2) + Math.Pow(b1-b2, 2));
```

This is similar to DeltaE 76(lab), but it has the same drawbacks where the perceptual difference is not taken into account.

PLEASE don't just do a Google search and paste the first thing you see! There are lots of Delta RGB formula's out there that may be found, but do not take perceptual differences into account. If you have knowledge of this, please comment and/or paste any links to code samples. Also, I already have conversion from RGB to Lab/Lch and then into De2000/cmc. I am not looking for that.

Comment: Hi, did you come up with a successful delta-e formula, I am just looking into this and would like to understand more. my email is on my profile if you have time to contact me. Thanks.

Comment: I set up a small lib that compares colors with algorithms like CIE76, CIE84, CMC l:C, and DE2000.

They all convert to other spaces, so this doesn't answer your question...but at least it's open source and (I hope) easy to use:

var deltaE = myRgb.Compare(myOtherRgb,new Cie1976Comparison());
https://github.com/THEjoezack/ColorMine

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you already gave the only right answer: conversion to a perceptual color space, where the simple delta formula makes sense.

Brilliant color scientists have been trying to answer the question of perceptual color differences for over a century. They've looked for a simple RGB formula that works, but human perception is just too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't find them:

- http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=FAQS&H=05#text5
- http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT